# Calling js from Dart

Tags: javascript, dart, angular-dart

How do I go call code like this from Dart?

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
```

I know I can call functions using the "package:js/js.dart" package, like this

```
@JS("Plotly.plot")
external plot(DivElement element, List<PlotData> plotData, Margin margin);
```

...but calling a function on an element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not 100% clear what you're asking, but I *think* you're asking how to call arbitrary methods on a JS object. It's not super easy to do this (it is better to write typed interfaces). You have two options:

1. Use [`package:js/js_util.dart`](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/js/latest/js_util/js_util-library.html) and invoke `callMethod`.
2. Write a [`@JS()`-annotated `class`](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/js/latest/) for what you want.

For the first, you can write the following:

```
import 'package:js/js_util.dart' as js;

void openDatePicker(Object elements) {
  js.callMethod(elements, 'datepicker', []);
}
```

... not super elegant (or well typed), but it works. I'd only recommend doing this if you really just need to invoke a single method, and don't expect to be calling other methods or passing complex arguments.

For the latter, you can still use `@JS()` technique. For example:

```
@JS()
external JQueryElements $(String selector);

@JS()
// Because this doesn't "really" align to a class in the JS/DOM.
@anonymous
abstract class JQueryElements {
  @JS()
  external void datepicker();
}
```

... and you could use it like this:

```
void main() {
  $('.datepicker').datepicker();
}
```

Comment: What would return values look like?